# Get a set of TableRow in TableLayout by findViewById

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

Have LinearLayout, where some parts may be invisible by some conditions.
E.g.

```
<LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout1">
     <!-- set of childs -->
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout2">
     <!-- set of childs -->
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In LinearLayout I can get any child part(with his layouts) from main layout by findViewById and change it visibility(programmatically ofcourse). Layouts with ids uses like wrappers for set of childs.

Can I do something like this in TableLayout ? I meen, get a set of TableRow from layout by findViewById and change his visibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html:

> Although the typical child of a TableLayout is a TableRow, you **can actually use any View subclass as a direct child of TableLayout. The View will be displayed as a single row that spans all the table columns.**

So, I do it like this

```
<TableLayout>
  <TableRow><!-- some data --></TableRow>
  <TableLayout android:id="rowsSet1">
    <TableRow><!-- some data --></TableRow>
    <TableRow><!-- some data --></TableRow>
    <TableRow><!-- some data --></TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
  <TbaleRow><!-- some data --></TableRow>
  <TableLayout android:id="rowsSet2">
    <TableRow><!-- some data --></TableRow>
    <TableRow><!-- some data --></TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
</TableLayout>
```

Now I can get set of rows by findViewById and, for example, hide them.

Answer (score 0):

`TableRow`inherits from `LinearLayout`. It can do everything that a linear layout can. So yes, you can assign it an ID and change its visibility.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html

Comment: I need set of TableRows, not one.

Comment: If you want to make individual table rows invisible, you will have to retrieve them individually using findViewById. If you want to make all of them invisible, you could set the whole table to invisible... I'm not sure if I understand the issue correctly.

Comment: I think, what should be more elegant solution, because retrieve by findViewById each row is not practical, furthermore they all must have id's.